# How are cluster size, buffer size and packet size related for performance?

Tags: http, filesystems, files, performance-tuning, file-transfer

I'm creating a server on an embedded system. I have a FAT filesystem on an SD card which contains **a file, which should be sent via HTTP to some client over wifi** that connects to the system.

At first I tried to read the file byte by byte, which was very slow.
To improve the file reading, I introduced a buffer. I read from the file to the buffer and then write the buffer content to the stream that is sent to the client:

```
file -> buffer -> network
```

- Increasing the buffer size increases the data transfer rate. I assume this is because of the reduced number of read operations to the file system.
- However, an arbitrary large buffer (say 5000 bytes) is counterproductive. I suspect this is due to bufferbloat. The server spends too much time filling the buffer, which confuses the network.

Apparently, there's some optimal buffer size, where read speed is increased without causing a slowdown due to buffer bloat.

I would like to increase the overal performance in terms of data transfer rate. Currently I get like 3Mbi/s which is too slow. I am in control of the buffer size and the cluster size. Can I improve the performance of the system by making good choices for those two values?

1. Should buffer size and cluster size ideally be the same? Should buffer size be some integer multiple of the cluster size in general (possibly >1)?
2. Should I choose the two in some way that they also line up with the network payload size? (I'm not much experienced with networks and don't know if there even is such a thing as a fixed payload size)

How do I decide on those sizes to increase data transfer rate?

Comment: Any tuning you do is essentially pointless as it's the SD card that is highly likely to be the lowest performing part of the IO chain.

Comment: @Chopper3 going from single byte read/write to a buffer of 300 byte increased the speed significantly, which suggests that tweaking the sizes has an effect. I agree that eventually the card *will* be the bottleneck and I'd love to have that problem, however, at the moment, the issues appear to be elsewhere. Point in case: the class 4 card supposedly does 4MB/s which I am very far away from at the moment with 3Mbit/s.

Comment: What the hell kind of filesystem only pulls files byte-by-byte? or are you writing this code yourself?

Comment: @Chopper3 I am indeed writing this code myself.

Comment: Ah, then you didn't read the text we put in the login page about what we are and aren't for - I think you probably want our sister site stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Chopper3 [so] is about fixing code, right? I don't have particular code to share or need help implementing it. I need to know the fundamentals (about how the sizes interact) in order to make an educated decision myself how to do this. If you think this is off-topic here, go ahead and flag it for migration. I doubt that my question will be well received there, because it has no code in it. I came here specifically (and not so) to understand how those sizes interact. [ask] states this site is about *managing the hardware or software of servers*, I do that.

Comment: This is managing existing software for servers, not about implementing software... If I were you, I would install nginx or some other web server there and let it handle sending the file. There is no point in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I'm not reinventing the wheel here. I'm using readymade libraries for file access and networking. The question is how exactly I should manage these software components to get the best performance. This is an embedded system. How exactly do I "install" nginx there? And what of my problems would it actually solve? Does it automatically determine the right buffer, cluster and package sizes?

Comment: nginx has optimized the process of sending files via HTTP protocol, that is why it is one of the most widely used web server software around. If installing nginx is not an option, you could check its source code how it handles the sending of files. It could also be that your libraries are not optimal for your purpose.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I'm using a library specific to the embedded platform that I'm using. What optimisation did nginx undergo in this regard?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't looked at nginx source code to see how it has been implemented. All I know that the implementation is good based on my experience on using it. Other elements in the device networking implementation might also pose limitations on the transfer rate.